# Crystal Report logon failed in IIS 7

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have used crystal report with VS2010 with IIS 7. I can connect the DB from WEB application. However, it throws "Logon Failed", if the application run with IIS 7.

I tried with following VB.NET code

```
Dim boConnectionInfo As New ConnectionInfo()

boConnectionInfo.ServerName = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings("CRServerName").ToString

boConnectionInfo.DatabaseName = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings("CRDatabaseName").ToString

boConnectionInfo.UserID = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings("CRUserID").ToString

boConnectionInfo.Password = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings("CRPassword").ToString


boReportDocument.VerifyDatabase()

boReportDocument.Refresh()
```

it throws following exceptions

> Log on failed.
>   at
>   CrystalDecisions.CrystalReports.Engine.ReportDocument.VerifyDatabase()
>   at IPSReport.btnViewPort_Click(Object sender, EventArgs e) in
>   C:\inetpub\wwwroot\IPS_CrysRpt_VS2010\Report.aspx.vb:line 383    at
>   System.Web.UI.WebControls.Button.OnClick(EventArgs e)    at
>   System.Web.UI.WebControls.Button.RaisePostBackEvent(String
>   eventArgument)    at
>   System.Web.UI.WebControls.Button.System.Web.UI.IPostBackEventHandler.RaisePostBackEvent(String
>   eventArgument)    at
>   System.Web.UI.Page.RaisePostBackEvent(IPostBackEventHandler
>   sourceControl, String eventArgument)    at
>   System.Web.UI.Page.RaisePostBackEvent(NameValueCollection postData)
>   at System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequestMain(Boolean
>   includeStagesBeforeAsyncPoint, Boolean includeStagesAfterAsyncPoint)

Could you please help me out to find the cause of error and solutions for it?

Thanks
VG

Answer (score 0):

You haven't ascertained whether the values being read from the Web.Config file via the AppSettings static class are the values you expect them to be.

If by saying "I can connect the DB from WEB application." you mean "I can connect to the database inside Visual Studio but my application won't connect when deployed and running under IIS" then the answer is that the connection settings being read by the application when you deploy it under IIS are not the same as the credentials you are using when you connect in Visual Studio. Typically this is because you haven't deployed the Web.Config containing the credentials correctly.

To determine whether this is true; (1) look at the contents of the Web.Config you have deployed on IIS, (2) output the credentials you are reading during your connection attempt using some logging framework (or just write them as the HTML output). You will probably find they are not the credentials you think they are.

Comment: Thanks a lot Philip for your immediate response. I am getting the same exception while running the website application before deploy into IIS. But, it is working fine if I run this as WebApplication.

Comment: Thanks a lot Philip for your immediate response.  As per your suggestion, I have tested. I am getting the same value as connection settings from web.config file, and I am getting the same exception while running the website application before deploy into IIS. But, it is working fine if I run this as WebApplication.

Comment: Ok, when you say "Run as a Web Application" what precisely do you mean - do you mean that you are running it under Visual Studio ? Is the IIS installation on the same PC as you are running the application within Visual Studio or is it on a different PC (i.e. is it on a Server). If its on a different Server can you Ping the SQL Server name you are using in your connection string (i.e. is the server your database on actually visible to the IIS Server ?)